# Server load performance require php

Tags: php, require

after looking and trying to find the answer over google i cant find it. Actually my question is do it will affect the server load if i lets say require
a 10kb file vs require a 100 kb file ?

Comment: Why don't you try testing it?

Comment: i try but my localhost is so fast that i cant even see the difference and i do not know how to test it in another way ..

Comment: Try [ApacheBench](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ab).

Comment: thanks will try it

Comment: If you're not using an OpCache then it can eventually have an impact on the CPU if the file is included many times over and over.  The size itself has less to do with it, but rather how many PHP statements and expressions there are.  The time to tokenize that file over and over has a cost.  [OpCache](http://php.net/opcache) will reduce this impact greatly when enabled.

Comment: the file actually do not contain any statement it is only functions inside example actually i have 2 file function1.php that is 20 kb and function2.php that is 50kb should i be better only load 1 with all content of both file. My concern is in some part of my script i call only require on function1.php thinking im saving resource but if i do not save resource t a noticable point i will include a global function file

Comment: actually im working on a chat system and that file will be required every 3 sec